# Evaluation of Integrals involving Summation and Product functions

Tags: integration, summation

The integral given below involves both summation and product functions of $r$. LCM of the denominators from summation does cancels out with the numerator from the product but to no help. Some more insight needed.

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\sum_{r=1}^{2013}\frac {x}{x^2+r^2}\right)\left(\prod_{r=1}^{2013} (x^2+r^2) \right)dx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is supposed to be about logarithmic differentiation. Since $\frac d{dx}\ln(f(x))=\frac1{f(x)}\frac d{dx}f(x)$, we can reverse this to get $\frac d{dx}f(x)=f(x)\frac d{dx}\ln(f(x))$. In this case
$$\begin{align}\frac d{dx}\prod_{r=1}^{2013}(x^2+r^2)&=\prod_{r=1}^{2013}(x^2+r^2)\frac d{dx}\ln\prod_{r=1}^{2013}(x^2+r^2)\\
&=\prod_{r=1}^{2013}(x^2+r^2)\frac d{dx}\sum_{r=1}^{2013}\ln(x^2+r^2)\\
&=\prod_{r=1}^{2013}(x^2+r^2)\sum_{r=1}^{2013}\frac{2x}{x^2+r^2}\end{align}$$
So we see that
$$\begin{align}\int_0^1\left(\sum_{r=1}^{2013}\frac x{x^2+r^2}\right)\left(\prod_{r=1}^{2013}(x^2+r^2)\right)dx&=\left.\frac12\prod_{r=1}^{2013}(x^2+r^2)\right|_0^1\\
&=\frac12\prod_{r=1}^{2013}(1+r^2)-\frac12(2013!)^2\end{align}$$